# Angular Cli 6.2.x branch Source, npm install error 'npm audit fix'

Tags: node.js, angular, build, angular-cli, npm-install

I got angular-cli source code from git to customize cli options. but npm install make message like this.

```
npm install
npm WARN deprecated spdx@0.5.2: see spdx-expression-parse, spdx-satisfies, &c.

> husky@0.14.3 install D:\dev\git\personal\angularCli\node_modules\husky
> node ./bin/install.js

husky
setting up Git hooks
done

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
added 369 packages from 415 contributors and audited 1352 packages in 25.428s
found 1 moderate severity vulnerability
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I just tried npm install in angular-cli root folder to edit code and build angular cli.

I tried npm install again and again. but got same result.
is this problem? if it is problem, how can i fix it?

node version: 8.11.4
npm versino: 6.1.0
os: window 10

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have got 1 moderate severity vulnerability

Run the following command

```
npm audit fix
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. since angular cli 6.x version, 'yarn' have some part of module dependency config about packages.
after git clone from angular-cli repo, we should type command 'yarn'.

if you don't have yarn

```
npm install -g yarn
yarn
```

after do that, npm install, npm run build and then angular-cli project make dist folder and output. in windows and osx works